# how to display the result in textbox of a row in datagridview?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I want to create a small program to create an arithmetic operator that adds two numbers together.

when I double click a cell in my datagridview, then my textbox outside will display the result of this row.

for example:

```
1  3
3  5
2  8
```

I also create a class for my program, the class's name is Cac, and the method in it is

```
public int CacAB()
    {
        int result= a + b;
        return result;
    }
```

the result for first row should be 4, second row should be 8 and the third row should be 10.

my textbox's name is just textBox1 and my datagridview's name is just datagridview1, how to make it? thanks very much.

I know I need create a method like:"dataGridView1_CellDoubleClick" so far.

Answer (score 1):

So I think may be you want to achieve this

```
private void DataGridView1_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
     int firstValue = Convert.ToInt32(DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("Column1").Value.ToString());

     int secondValue = Convert.ToInt32(DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("Column2").Value.ToString());

     textBox.Text = (firstValue + secondValue).ToString();
}
```